# Android Spawn Enemies by time

Tags: android

I am developing a game that increases its level by time. Also increases the number of enemies that's spawned, however, i don't really know exactly where to put the codes of updating my enemies.

And I'm having problems in using the time as my reference, I created a Time class where it stores the beginTime(System.currenttimemillis) and timediff(System.currenttimemillis-beginTime), and I instantiate them in my thread class, so it will get the current time state of the game, however, when I am using it in my gamepanel class specifically in the update method, when comparing the value it is storing, it ignores the condition even though it has a value.

```
if(time.getTimeDiff()==3000){
    enemy.update();
}
```

the game should start after 3 secs, but if I put the condition, no enemy will come even though I set 1 dummy.

i will really appreaciate it if somebody can clearly explain me everything.

Comment: Are you sure your code passes by that comparison every millisecond? Shouldn't it be `if(time.getTimeDiff() >= 3000)` ?

Comment: Ok i'll try to implement that, thanks

Comment: it didn't work at all..my enemies should move from right to left when time.getTimeDiff() reached or exceed 3000 millis

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this?

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start > 3000)
{
   updateEnemy();
   start = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to increase the difficulty, replace 3000 with a variable.. like:
    int waitTime = 3000;

Then get the start time of the game.

```
long gameStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Later check:

```
if (timeEllaspsedSinceStart > howManySecondsTilLevelUp)
{
     waitTime -= howMuchLessYouWantToWait;
}
```

Comment: If your enemies didn't move, it's probably in your updateEnemy() method. This wouldn't move your method. It simply provides a check to see if 3000 ms has passed.

Comment: My friend told me that my problem is my thread, and even if i place a diffent code for time updates, it still ignores the condition i put in my if statement, everytime the thread class updates the gamepanel class, conditions related to time is ignored, but conditions related to the position of images and conditions about collisions were not ignored.

Comment: I can't really look at your code, but maybe this tutorial will help you: http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame3.html There's a simple thread there that just updates the gameboard every few milliseconds.

Comment: and what i want is, after 3 seconds when the game started, my enemies will start updating/moving..

and I having some difficulty in creating a class for enemies so I'm calling them 1 by 1

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

This is a class I wrote that will act as a timer:

```
public class Timer {

    Long startTime;
    int delayTime;

    public Timer() {

    }

    public Timer(int delayTime) {
        this.delayTime = delayTime;

    }

    public void setDelayTime(int delayTime) {
        this.delayTime = delayTime;

    }

    public boolean delay() {
        if(this.startTime == null) {
            this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        if(startTime + this.delayTime < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            this.startTime = null;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public void reset() {
        this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }


}
```

Now in your update method you could check if a new enemy should be spawned like this:

```
Timer spawnEnemyTimer = new Timer(5000); // 5 seconds

public void update() {
if(spawnEnemyTimer.update() == true) {
// spawn new enemy!
// Timer will automatically reset!
}

}
```

I hope this helps!